# Most efficient if statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, if-statement

I would like to write a function that takes integer numbers `x`, `y`, `L` and `R` as parameters and returns `True` if `x**y` lies in the interval `(L, R]` and `False` otherwise.

I am considering several ways to write a conditional statement inside this function:

1. `if L < x ** y <= R:`
2. `if x ** y > L and x ** y <= R:`
3. `if x ** y in range(L + 1, R + 1):`

Why is option 1 the most efficient in terms of execution time ?

Comment: Have you considered testing it? 1 would clearly be more efficient than 2 as `x ** y` is only evaluated once, and I'd guess the `range` call in 3 would make it slower unless you could factor it out, but **you could validate that**, using e.g. `timeit`.

Comment: Did you do any timings?

Comment: since all the 3 are not to complicated to implement I will try them all and check the results

Comment: The first one is the most readable and fastest.

Comment: I'll rephrase my question.

Comment: Because (emphasis mine) [*"`x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that **`y` is evaluated only once**"*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Comment: Note: Option #3 will fail if `x**y` evaluates to a `float`.

Comment: @tobias_k: Technically, it won't _fail_ if the `float` compares equal to some `int`, but yeah, it will behave differently (for `float` that aren't equal to any `int` value), and it will break the Python 3.2 `O(1)` membership optimization of `range` (it will revert to iterating and comparing each element in the `range`). I did update my answer to mention this though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both #1 and #3 avoid recalculating `x ** y`, where #2 must calculate it twice.

On Python 2, #3 will be terrible, because it must compute the whole contents of the `range`. On Python 3.2+, it doesn't have to (`range` is smart, and can properly determine mathematically whether an `int` appears in the `range` without actually iterating, in constant time), but it's at best equivalent to #1, since creating the `range` object at all has some overhead.

As `tobias_k` mentions in the comments, if `x ** y` produces a `float`, #3 will be slower (breaks the Python 3.2+ `O(1)` membership testing optimization, requiring an implicit loop over all values), and will get different results than #1 and #2 if the value is not equal to any `int` value in the `range`. That is, testing `3.5 in range(1, 5)` returns `False`, and has to check `3.5` against `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` individually before it can even tell you that much.

Basically, stick to #1, it's going to be the only one that avoids redundant computations and avoids creating a ton of values for comparison on both Py 2 and Py3. #3 is not going to be much (if at all) slower on Python 3.2+, but it does involve creating a `range` object that isn't needed here, and won't be quite logically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The first one has to evaluate `x**y` only once, so it should be faster than the second (also, more readable). The third one would have to loop over the iterator (in python 2, so it should be slower than both) or make two comparisons (in python 3, so it is no better than the first one). Keep the first one.

Comment: it's only in python2 that `range` creates a list. In Python3 it's not that bad (but still worse than the other two)

Comment: The third one doesn't involve any sort of implicit loop on modern Python 3.2+ (`range` is smarter than that on Py3.2+), but your overall conclusion is correct; #1 will win or at least tie any other solution on any Python version.